# How test cdkConnectedOverlay in Angular

Tags: angular

I try to write test for my component. How can I achieve cdkConnectedOverlay and check input parameters conditionFormOverlayOrigin, isConditionFormOverlayOpen?

```html
<ng-template
    *ngIf="isConditionFormOverlayOpen && conditionFormOverlayOrigin"
    cdkConnectedOverlay
    [cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass]="'transparent-backdrop'"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop]="true"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="conditionFormOverlayOrigin"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isConditionFormOverlayOpen"
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

angular allows you to find directive insstance of your component

```
const overlayDirective = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(CdkConnectedOverlay))
   .injector.get(CdkConnectedOverlay)

....
expect(overlayDirective.cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass).toBe('transparent-backdrop');
```

Comment: It's not working
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null'

I add property link to my component
@ViewChild(CdkConnectedOverlay) connectedOverlayDirective: CdkConnectedOverlay;

And then use in tests

Comment: you still can query this child through the debug element, but you should do it afterit appears, not before. make sure detectChanges() is called before it